# How to add fragment of DOM module into existing document using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one html file, which have two div elements with various nested elements.

```
<div id="App1" class="app">
    <p class="header">Application 1 : User Registration</p>
    <form>
      <label>User Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name..">
      <div>
        <input type="radio" name="Gender"> Male
        <input type="radio" name="Gender"> Female
      </div>
      <label>Address</label>
      <textarea></textarea>
      <br/>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id="App2" class="app">
    <p class="header">Application 2 : Global car search</p>
    <form>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Make Name
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="Car make company..">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Car Type
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="radio" name="Type"> Old
            <input type="radio" name="Type"> New
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="submit" value="Search">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Now I used `remove()` method to remove `#App1` from the document

```
var app1 = document.querySelector('#App1');
app1.remove();
//how to add back ???
```

Now what is the best way to add this fragment again into document ?

[Plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/p2W0UMy99sG6NkhvkDDn?p=preview)

Please suggest, possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

Make a reference to the parent of `app1`

```
var app1 = document.querySelector('#App1');
app1Parent = app1.parentElement;
app1.remove();
app1Parent.appendChild(app1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.cloneNode(true)` and `.insertBefore()`

```js
var app1 = document.querySelector("#App1");
var clone = app1.cloneNode(true);
app1.remove();
var sibling = document.querySelector("#App2");
setTimeout(function() {
  sibling.parentElement.insertBefore(clone, sibling);
}, 3000);
```

```css
.app {
  float: left;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 2px dashed #ccc;
  min-height: 400px;
  min-width: 45%;
  width: inherit;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="App1" class="app">
    <p class="header">Application 1 : User Registration</p>
    <form>
      <label>User Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name..">
      <div>
        <input type="radio" name="Gender"> Male
        <input type="radio" name="Gender"> Female
      </div>
      <label>Address</label>
      <textarea></textarea>
      <br/>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id="App2" class="app">
    <p class="header">Application 2 : Global car search</p>
    <form>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Make Name
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="Car make company..">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Car Type
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="radio" name="Type"> Old
            <input type="radio" name="Type"> New
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="submit" value="Search">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

plnkr https://plnkr.co/edit/2vjQHeGGZYWxJENFaZuA?p=preview